# Adding specific identification tags to existing identification questions

Tags: discussion, tags

As of right now if you want to search the questions about identifying a particular animal you can use the [animal-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification) to search for them.

However if you wanted to look up all of the questions about identifying fungi or trees or man-made objects in the wild or plants or scat you would have to use multiple tags.

**This does not seem consistent to me or user friendly.**

What I would like to propose is to create tags for each specific category in **order to make it easier to search** and to **make the tags consistent.**

Currently the naming convention is something-identification, I will leave it to another question to decide if that should be changed to the identify-this type of names.

Specifically I would like to create the following tags and apply them to the questions listed below,

[fossil-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fossil-identification)

- [Identification of 3 toed 6 inch long dinosaur tracks](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16972/identification-of-3-toed-6-inch-long-dinosaur-tracks)

[plant-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-identification)

- [What are these small blue berries growing in clusters on a medium size bush in Southern Ontario, Canada?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17074/what-are-these-small-blue-berries-growing-in-clusters-on-a-medium-size-bush-in-s)
- [What is this plant with fluffy white flowers in the Canadian Rockies?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16912/what-is-this-plant-with-fluffy-white-flowers-in-the-canadian-rockies)
        [What are these clusters of tiny dark blue berries found in the Southern Canadian Rockies?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16911/what-are-these-clusters-of-tiny-dark-blue-berries-found-in-the-southern-canadian)
- [Is this poison sumac?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16909/is-this-poison-sumac)
- [What is this plant in England with large veined leaves and multi-part buds?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16109/what-is-this-plant-in-england-with-large-veined-leaves-and-multi-part-buds)
- [What is this really tall grass-like plant?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/what-is-this-really-tall-grass-like-plant)
- [How can I identify Woolly Adelgid on a Hemlock tree?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15578/how-can-i-identify-woolly-adelgid-on-a-hemlock-tree)

[fungi-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fungi-identification)

- [What are these mushrooms found in Fukuoka, Japan?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16595/what-are-these-mushrooms-found-in-fukuoka-japan)
- [Is this fungus on a birch tree Chaga?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/is-this-fungus-on-a-birch-tree-chag)
- [What are these fungi that I've found growing on a dead birch?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/what-are-these-fungi-that-ive-found-growing-on-a-dead-birch)

[tree-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tree-identification)

- [What is this tree with shiny leaves and a fuzzy seed pod?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16848/what-is-this-tree-with-shiny-leaves-and-a-fuzzy-seed-pod)
- [What kind of tree produces these long multi-seed pods?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15016/what-kind-of-tree-produces-these-long-multi-seed-pods)
- [What kind of tree produces these seed pods looking like spiky balls?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14950/what-kind-of-tree-produces-these-seed-pods-looking-like-spiky-balls)
- [Can anyone help with identifying this tree?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13719/can-anyone-help-with-identifying-this-tree)

[manmade-object-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manmade-object-identification)

- [What are these rusted metal objects found on a beach?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/what-are-these-rusted-metal-objects-found-on-a-beach)
- [What is this floating raft-like object in the waters of a reservoir in Massachusetts?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/what-is-this-floating-raft-like-object-in-the-waters-of-a-reservoir-in-massachus)
- [Wooden (or natural) obstacles in "the wild" looking like horse-jump obstacles](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15617/wooden-or-natural-obstacles-in-the-wild-looking-like-horse-jump-obstacles)

[gear-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gear-identification)

- [What model of Hanwag boots are those?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/16566/what-model-of-hanwag-boots-are-those)
- [Can anyone identify this JanSport external frame backpack?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17215/can-anyone-identify-this-jansport-external-frame-backpack)

[scat-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scat-identification)

- [Scat Identification on Upper Yosemite Falls Trail](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/scat-identification-on-upper-yosemite-falls-trail)
- [Is this yucky thing scat or slime mold?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/is-this-yucky-thing-scat-or-slime-mold)

Comment: "scat" is a weird one to me. That's not a word that's commonly used in outside the US. Though I suppose the questions have that in the title so it can't do any harm

Comment: Scat is certainly the normal term used in Britain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said before, I think these tags make sense, so I see no reason why not to use them.

I do not agree with replacing/removing [identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) though - not unless these tags are more established (except maybe [plant-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plant-identification), with at least 6 questions, which is still not much). As Liam wrote in the other questions:

> [...] at the moment the [animal-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-identification) has 46 questions and [identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) has 30. Making this grouping more specific is just going to scatter the information and likely lower the SEO value. If we had a lot more questions in these subjects and they needed further sub dividing then this would make sense. As it stands I don't think it does. So we shouldn't change these tags or re-tag the questions tagged by them.

Given you already went through all that trouble and the tags are useful, my vote is for adding the tags to the questions you proposed but also leaving [identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification) on them.

Comment: This seems very sensible to me